# Comparing two arrays using dictionary order in an array of arrays (java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

please bear with me because this one will take a little bit of explaining

I have an array of arrays and i need to sort them as if they were words (dictionary sorting/ lexicographically) for the lowest array

for example
    [[1,36,0,0],
    [1,0,2,5],
    [3,0,7,1],
    [5,0,10,7]]

Finding the lowest should return the 2nd array [1,0,2,5] as 1 is less than 3 or 5 in the 1st index of each array, and 0 is less than 36 when comparing between the first array and second at the 2nd element of each array (this could theoretically go to the last element of course and the arrays could be equal)

I've tried building them as a string by iterating over the elements (so line 1 would be 13600,2 would be 3025, 3 would be 3071, 4 would be 50107) but this method makes finding the lowest one incorrect when dealing with elements with 2 or more digits

I can't think of a better way of doing this than having a number of 'lowest value found' counter variables for each element. Does anyone have any guidance here? If it's possible to do so please explain at an intermediate level(ty).

Also: the indexes need to stay the same so i can't use .sort (if that would even work)

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, you need to compare the entries individually:

```
Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int index, aentry, bentry;
        index = 0;
        while (index < a.length && index < b.length) {
            aentry = a[index];
            bentry = b[index];
            if (aentry < bentry) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (aentry > bentry) {
                return 1;
            }
            ++index;
        }
        if (a.length < b.length) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.length > b.length) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

(With Java8 you could do that with a lambda.)

If you want the indexes not to change, you'll have to adapt that as it sorts the array in-place.

Comment: You beat me! Nevertheless I wonder why you didn't placed the length comparison before the values comparison. If that were the case, you could reduce time complexity from O(N) [N = min(len(a), len(b))] to O(1) for many cases (those where lengths are not equal).

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo: Because to my mind, [3, 2, 1] should appear *after* [1, 2, 3, 4], not before it. :-)

Comment: We differ in our point of view, for me shorter arrays should appear before larger ones. However your point of view seems to match better the OP's: "...dictionary sorting/ lexicographically... " it is true that in the dictionary "apple" is located before "clue". So +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom comparator and Java's sort methods:

```
class ArrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]> 
{
      @Override
      public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
          int ret = Integer.compare(a.length, b.length);
          if(ret != 0) return ret;
          for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
          {
              if(a[i] == b[i]) continue;
              else if(a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
              else return -1;
          }
          return 0;
      }
  }
```

Example of use:

```
        List<int[]> larr = new ArrayList<>();
        int [] arr = {1,2,3};
        larr.add(arr);

        int [] arr2 = {0,2,3};
        larr.add(arr2);

        int [] arr3 = {5};
        larr.add(arr3);

        Collections.sort(larr, new ArrayComparator());

        for(int [] xel: larr)
        {
            for(int xelv: xel)
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(xelv));
            System.out.println();
        }
```

It prints:

```
5
023
123
```

**EDIT**

After comparing T.J's solution I noticed that you may want lexicographic order to dominate over length order, if that is the case, this is my version of that type of comparator:

```
class ArrayComparator implements Comparator<int[]> 
{
      @Override
      public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
          for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length, b.length); i++)
          {
              if(a[i] == b[i]) continue;
              else if(a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
              else return -1;
          }
          return Integer.compare(a.length, b.length);
      }
  }
```